# CakePHP, URLs, and SEO

Tags: cakephp, seo

I was explaining to our SEO specialist that cakephp url structure is domain/controller/view/params

so to view a particular product the URL might be something like this:

> example.com/products/show/product-name-slug

This would then map to the `show` function on the `products controller` with the `product-name-slug` as a parameter so it could render the correct product page.

He thought this was good but asked if I could name the controller `p` and the view `d` so the url would then be:

> example.com/p/d/product-name-slug

Since this would make the appropriate keywords (product-name-slug) have a higher ratio over the entire url.

I understand where he is coming from, from a SEO perspective but this make no sense from a programming perspective giving controllers and views single letter names.

Does the ambiguous controller/view names in the URL make that much of a difference? If so, what would be a good compromising solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

having additional route in configuration:
example.com/seo/product-name-slug would make code and SEO person happy

```
Router::connect(
   '/seo/:slug',
   array('controller' => 'products', 'action' => 'show'),
   array(
       'pass' => array('slug')
   )
);
```

Comment: The last array that sets `id=>.+` what does that do?

Comment: a bit of overkill, it was supposed to be any string regexp

Answer (score 0):

It makes a big difference what is in your URL. I never ever used the default URL structure of CakePHP. It is good to have it by default, but it would make an unacceptable constraint.

Cake wouldn't be worthy to be called a framework if it couldn't map actions to arbitrary URLs http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#route-elements

You can even match regexp to actions:

```
Router::connect(
    '/:controller/:year/:month/:day',
    array('action' => 'index', 'day' => null),
    array(
        'year' => '[12][0-9]{3}',
        'month' => '0[1-9]|1[012]',
        'day' => '0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]'
    )
);
```